# Tiles internationalization

Tags: struts2, tiles

I am using internationalization in my web application using struts2 and tiles. it works for messages defined in messages_en.properties and messages.properties. The problem I am facing concerns titles of my web pages. I have set up two tiles definitions files, one for french tiles-defs.xml and the other one for English tiles-defs_en.xml. On an all my actions, I have put the i18n interceptor. But when I request a language change, my titles don't change. Is someone who have a beginning of solution?

Thanks a lot

This is my link to my locale action :

```
  <s:url var="urlfr" action="locale">
            <s:param name="request_locale">fr</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:a href="%{urlfr}">
            <img title="francais" alt=""
                src="/baseline/pages/images/flag-fr.gif">
        </s:a>
    &nbsp;
    <s:url var="urlen" action="locale">
            <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:a href="%{urlen}">
            <img title="englais" alt="" src="/baseline/pages/images/flag-gb.gif">
        </s:a>
```

My locale action only return success, and this is my struts.xml where I declared my actions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />


<package name="user" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="post" class="domain.PostOnlyInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="postStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="post" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <action name="listPaysAction" class="regionAction" method="listePaysParRegion">
        <interceptor-ref name="params" />
        <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <result name="success" type="tiles">accueil</result>
    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Show code. This really shouldn't be a tiles issue, it just assembles views. If the views are not doing i18n correctly it should be a struts2/jsp issue. Also don't see the need for a french/english tile. Could see possible reason for tiles that support languages with different layout flows but these are both left-to-right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for me that works.

To set the locale so that tiles will use the tiles_fr.xml, do this:

```
Locale locale = LocaleUtility.langToLocale("fr");
session.setAttribute(DefaultLocaleResolver.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
```

That is if you have access to your HttpSession.

I was trying to set the tiles and struts locale to use "fr" in a Filter.  So I have access to my HttpSession:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
Locale locale = LocaleUtility.langToLocale("fr"); // fr is hard coded for now.

Config.set(session, Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
session.setAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
session.setAttribute(DefaultLocaleResolver.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
```

Apparently, the

```
Config.set(session, Config.FMT_LOCALE, locale);
```

doesn't really do anything.  I've seen other say it works - but it doesn't work for tiles.  But I left it there.  Just in case I should need it in jstl too.

But doing the above will make your global_fr.properties as well as your tiles_fr.xml pick up.

Comment: It worked, but I use `Locale locale=new Locale('language');` instead of `Locale locale = LocaleUtility.langToLocale("fr");`

Comment: yes. either way will work, whether you do `new Locale()` or `langToLocale()`, so long as you thing you set in in session is a `Locale` object, it will work.